# Adding button on top of Grid

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a User Control derived from Grid

1. How can i add a Button to the right top corner of the Grid User Control (Above the grid)?

I can create new custom control and do it. But i do not want to expose all the properties of the Grid again to the User.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar requirement once.
I managed this using extra panel with transparent background.

Following is pseudocode for the same

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="rootGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Margin = "0 50 50 0" Background="Blue">
    </Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="200" Height="100">
    </Button>
<Grid>
```